# Floating Action Button rectangular shaped (round corners) with text

Tags: android, androiddesignsupport, floating-action-button

I was wondering whether it could be possible to create a fab like this shown in this image from [material.io](https://material.io/design/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#theming) and how to create it. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is possible to create such widget

Comment: You need to just use **`android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_like"`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_play_white"
    app:cornerRadius="20dp"
    android:text="Test" />
```

Comment: Using this, the icon isn't centered. How come?